# How to remove an element from a list, referencing it by weakref?

Tags: python

How to remove a list's element by referencing it by weakref?

```
import weakref

class Object():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

object = Object()
list = [object]
print(list)

wr = weakref.ref(object)
list.remove(wr)
print(list)
```

This returns a `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the reference object:

```
>>> list.remove(wr())
>>> list
[]
```

> The original object can be retrieved by calling the reference object if the referent is still alive; if the referent is no longer alive, calling the reference object will cause `None` to be returned.
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.ref

Btw, don't use `object` or `list` as variable names, those are built-in objects.

Comment: Thanks, mate! I read that part a couple of times, but somehow missed its meaning.